Getting groovyx.net.http.EncoderRegistry.encodeForm() Error
I need to make a REST API PUT call in Groovy using RESTClient and json as the Content Type. This is what my code looks like:
def params = ["content": listOfSymbols.join(","), "privacy": "U", "collection": collection, "asOfDate": todaysDate, "sync": "Y", "postingId": id]
*(where listOfSymbols is an arrayList. collection, todaysDate, and id are variables.)*
*(body is supposed to be list of Json objects)*

def jsonBody = []
jsonBody.add(JsonOutput.toJson(params))

def response = restClient.put(
            path: sPath,
            headers: ["Content-Type": 'application/json', "Authorization": "Bearer ${token}", charset: 'UTF-8'],
            body: jsonBody,
            requestContentType: URLENC
    )

This gives me an error:
Caught generic exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovyx.net.http.EncoderRegistry.encodeForm() is applicable for argument types: (ArrayList, groovyx.net.http.ContentType) values: [[{"content":"abc,pqr","privacy":"U","collection":"test1","asOfDate":"2024-06-04","sync":"Y","postingId":"1"}], ...]

How do I fix this error?

What is the specification of your endpoint? Your are doing things all over the place?  Do you want to send a JSON body or want form-encoding? My guess is body: params, requestContentType: 'application/json' here...

I need to send a JSON body as a list.

Then body: [params], requestContentType: 'application/json' - you clearly don't want form encoding
